# html collapsed/expanded tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/) code to generate a tree in html, and the problem is, everytime I refresh the page the tree expands.

I want to create it so that when I open the page, some branches will be expanded and some collapsed, depending on an attribute it has.

For example:

```
<span><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Parent 1</span>
    <ul> childrens go here
    </ul>
<span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Parent 2</span> 
    <ul> childrens go here
    </ul>
```

When I open the page, I want to see Parent 2's children, but not Parent 1's.

I'm novice in html and completely new to css and javascript. So any suggestion would help.

Comment: I think you should use cookies.

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, it doesn't look like novice work at all.. just saying..

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/GpdgF/1721/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add at the start of the code the close of each element mark as collapsed using its icon class.

Code:

```
$('.tree li.parent_li > span').each(function(i,e){
    if ($(this).find('i').hasClass("icon-plus-sign")){
        $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q3DQ2/

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a class to certain elements which will cause them to be closed upon page load?

The simplest solution would be to add

`$(".start-closed").click();`

to the bottom of the JQuery and then add the class `start-closed` to the nodes you want to close upon page load.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dksNr/

Let me know if I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following right after your OnClick function:

```
//Collapse each node
$('.tree li.parent_li > span').each(function(){
   var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
   children.hide('fast');
   $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
});
```

With that it will go through each node and hide it.

One more way to do it would be to have it by default be hidden with:

```
style="display: none;"
```

on each node you want hidden